# ImageView Scaling: fix height variable width with maxWidth

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am going to show some images, but my constraint is as title. I want to make all images have same height but according to their width they must have different width. I just do not want to lose any part of the image when scaling. here is my code:

```
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_IssueFirstLookActivity_magas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:maxWidth="40dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

I tried all I could with different values of `android:scaleType` but get nowhere.
here is a figure that what I want but when I play with those properties it dose not scale it as I want for example some time it dose not show image width completely and it crops it badly. Another try  for example is `android:scaleType="fitStart"` which cause the width of my images to be fine but the heights are not fit anymore. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

andriod ImageView attributes does not support the requirement you said just by statically choosing combination of width,height and saleType in the layout xml.

Instead you can do it in the java code by actually finding the width for the image for a given fixed height and setting them programattically to each view in dp(make sure you do the pixel to dp calculation for achieving right output, salable across devices)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an extra dependency, you can do it with [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

```java
Picasso.get()
  .load(R.drawable.my_image_resource)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_placeholder)
  .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
  .resize(0, (int) imagefixedHeight)
  // optional:
  // .centerInside()
  .into(myImageView);
```